# Hide passwords from source code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been struggling with this question:
how can I hide passwords from my source code, that everyone can see on github,
for example:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :port                 => 587,
 :user_name            => my_user_name,
 :password             => my_password,
 :authentication       => 'plain',
 :enable_starttls_auto => true,
 :domain               => 'gmail.com'  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use environment variables, for easy setup you could check out the Figaro gem:

https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro